# Does BoneCP support XA Transactions?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, xa, bonecp

Any idea if BoneCP supports XA Transactions?

The list of features on the website doesn't mention anything about XA Transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only implements the DataSource interface, but not the XADataSource interface.